# How can I check if two GEP instructions are semantically equal or not?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I have two GEP instructions looking like below:

```
%size = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ArrayInfo, %struct.ArrayInfo* %0, i32 0, i32 0

...
%size = getelementptr inbounds %struct.ArrayInfo, %struct.ArrayInfo* %1, i32 0, i32 0
```

Essentially these two are accessing the same struct field. Is there a way to check if these two instructions are equivalent in llvm? I tried comparing pointers of GEPOperator (GEPOperator*), but it looks like they are different.

Comment: Semantic equality depends on the source language. Of course if the two have the [same type](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#a007e3ac7d87a0aa614ad9efbe698dbca) and [indices](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#a9cbd632c90e76301ccdf1c45aa2e5cb5) they'll usually be the same, but in some languages they can be the same even if they're different (C and java are examples of that), and it's not obvious to me whether [being inbounds](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GetElementPtrInst.html#a01f11934ce1bac24a7c9190d14686844) makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [isSameOperationAs()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Instruction.html#af6a9bd61f87556300ac75d893817d9ef). If you cast both `size` variables in your example to `llvm::Instruction` and call this method on one with the other as an argument, you'll get a `true` value.